# Can succubus be loyal to her lover?

Tags: mythical-creatures

Like in the title can a succubus be loyal to her lover or it has to have sexual intercourse men?

Comment: Can you give more background info on the succubus?

Comment: My feeling is that the answer must be no, within the traditional framework of mythology where Succubi reside.  (i.e. they are agents of the Adversary, and their only purpose is to corrupt.)  That said, this idea is fruitful ground for contemporary re-invention, which is a component of mythological canons such as the Ancient Greek material, which was "riffed on" and modified by successive generations of storytellers.  The example regarding succubi that leaps to mind is in the Preacher comic books, where a succubus and angel fall in love and face consequences for the betrayal of their masters.

Comment: PS the intent of the succubus is not sexual per se--that is merely the method or vehicle that particular infernal entity uses to corrupt the souls of mortals.  The masculine counterpart is the [incubus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incubus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not as fairly easy to answer as what you can expect. One of the huge problem we have is "succubuses" (or "succubi") are not well defined creatures.

### Hebraic sources

We have two main Hebraic sources:

1. The Alpa beta (or Alphabet of Ben Sira): That book is the one where the infamous [Lilith](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/who-what-is-lilith/1958#1958) appears and let's face it, this book is a giant troll book.I linked to you an analysis of Lilith I gave some time ago.
2. The Zohar: Another questionable book, certainly less than the AB, but still, cf the link I gave. There we find such demons, named the four queens of Hell (Lilith, Agrat Bat Malhat, Naamah, Eisheth Zenunim).

What we can see here is: Succubuses are clearly defined as female demons, and in the Zohar they are simply the mothers of all the demons (except Lilith, which is sterile). The Zohar is vastly used to build the Kabbalah, but sometimes it is a book difficult to understand or "follow" as I shown in the Lilith's answer.

### Middle age sources

Middle age is a "funky" time where people was debating over such questions as "Can God defecate ?" (yes they did). And during Middle Age there will be a lot of discussion on the nature of the succubuses.
The question of the sex and ability to reproduce of those demons has been question over and over.
Thomas of Aquinas suggested that succubuses and incubuses was a unique demon, switching sex, stealing semen as a female over human being male and using it on female to impregnate them. Merlin, in the Arthurian cycle is such a man (The usual name of such an offspring is 'cambion').
In the Malleus Maleficarium, another infamous troll book (this time in the very bad sense, because it has been quite read), the anti-witch book by excellence. In this book the succubus will steal some semen to human male, give it to an incubus (or shift into an incubus, depends) and impregnate a woman given her malformed offspring.

In substance Middle Age denied angels and demons any reproducing ability. But linking those demons with high sexual perversion they tried to find way to explain that.

### Meridiana

Now concerning purely your question, considering the small sources we have, and the fact they are often to be taken carefully, we have such a story with the "pope of year 1000", Sylvestre II, Gerbert d'Aurillac.

## Gerbert of Aurillac

Gerbert d'Aurillac was a fairly intellectual man in Middle Age. Because, as lots of Middle Age mathematicians, he took a great care studying muslim mathematicians, he was not so loved (he is one of the first men in Europe to use arabic numbers, way before Leonardo do Pisa, Fibonacci (roughly 200 years)).

## Walter Map's De nugis curialium

The story of Meridiana is known to us by Walter Map's De nugis Curilium written way after Gerbert's death.

He is supposed to have befriendeded a succubus Meridiana. She is supposed to have been her "dark council" and completely helped him to become the Pope. She is known to have warn him to never preach in Jerusalem. He unfortunately prayed in a church of Jerusalem. that is a clear example of a succubus showing loyal love to her "mate".

Comment: I feel like your casting works as "troll books" without explanation diminishes this answer.  That said, if you were to link, or at least cite, teh relevant passages, this would be an excellent answer.  (I partly ask b/c I know a little about these traditions, but it's not my area of focus, as I suspect is true of many Mythology contributors, so citation would help me validate the information and facilitate upvoting this answer...)

Comment: Fair enough.  I recognize that there aren't the same online resources available for this material as, say, the classical material, but I was able to satisfactory validate.  The Meridiana stuff is very interesting!

Comment: I hear you on the pricing issue on the more obscure material.  My first brush with medieval sources was on microfiche in a university library, and, imo, it's frustrating that the material is not all available online by now.  (I think it's especially important for these subjects b/c there are so many spurious contemporary sources on the internet.)   PS: Don't be shy about utilizing Stack Latin--Latin is not my strong suit either and they were enormously helpful with a recent answer where I needed corroboration of my own translation of a couple passages.